# How to find the frequency of elements that are list of list?

Tags: python

I am trying to obtain the frequency of each list in a list.
The following is my code

```
from collections import Counter
my_list=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
ctr=[]
ctr = Counter(my_list)
print(ctr[[1,2,3]])
```

This code works for list of numbers i.e. if `my_list=[1,2,3]`. But for list of list it does not work.
`ctr[[1,2,3]]` should print `2` but there is an error that is as follows

```
  TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Could Someone help?

Comment: What is not clear about the Error message? `Counter` creates a dictionary and you cannot have a dictionary with keys of type `list`. So it fails.

Comment: when you call two lists same, do you mean the sequence of their elements as well or just the elements

Comment: It is even the sequence of their elements that is important

Answer (score 2):

One solution:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

ctr = Counter(map(tuple, lst))

ctr[(1,2,3)]
# 2
```

**Explanation**

- `Counter` instances are dictionaries and therefore require immutable
  keys. Tuples are immutable, while lists are not.
- Moreover, `Counter` instances accept any iterable, not just lists.
- Performing the tuple conversion lazily means you don't have to create
  a fresh list.

Comment: I like this version better! +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Counter` creates a dictionary and you cannot have a dictionary with keys of type `list`. So when you feed a list of lists, it fails. To get over this issue, convert the inner lists to tuples like so:

```
from collections import Counter

my_list  = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
new_list = [tuple(x) for x in my_list]  # or overwrite with my_list = ..

ctr = Counter(new_list)    
print(ctr[(1, 2, 3)])  # -> 2
```

Comment: you mean `Counter(new_list)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oops.. Typo. Thanks!